# Android Exit button with alert dialog

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, exit

I am using the following code to exit my application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                startActivity(intent);
```

now when i press the exit, it should show the alert dialog. if  i pressed ok, close the application otherwise no.

Comment: What is your particular problem?

Comment: then write the code in the alertdialog ...whats the problem..

Comment: I used exit option as one icon in menu bar. how can i import alert there?

Comment: Create a button, set up an onClickListener, on click create an Alert Dialog with two buttons and, in your positive button (the one with the OK text) listener, copy your code.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

remove super.OnBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
           .setCancelable(false)
           .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    MyActivity.this.finish();
               }
           })
           .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.cancel();
               }
           });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the total alertdialog code from [this link..](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-alert-dialog-example/)
and in the positive button write like:

```
 .setPositiveButton("Logout",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
    //your_activity.finish();......(1)
            //otherwise use your code..
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);

    }
});
```